# PDF Merge on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf

I'm creating a couple of pdf invoices and want to merge them into one for easier printing after they've been created. I have this jquery code:

```
        $('#printinvoice').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "../ajaxcalls/print_invoice.php",

            data: {

                Order: itemstotake1

            },
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../ajax/pdf_merger.php",

                    data: {
                        PDFS: data
                    },

                    success: function (data1) {
                        alert(data1);
                        //window.location.assign('../tools/PDFMerger/samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf');
                        $('.group').removeClass('highlight');
                        itemstotake1 = [];
                    }


                });

            }
        });

});
```

I use PDFMerge, the Files are merged, but there is no response of my second success function.
Here's the PHP code (pdf_merger.php)

include '../tools/PDFMerger/PDFMerger.php';
    $files = $_POST['PDFS'];

```
$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('../tools/PDFMerger/samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all')
->addPDF('../tools/PDFMerger/samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all')
->addPDF('../tools/PDFMerger/samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all')
->merge('file', '../tools/PDFMerger/samplepdfs/TEST22.pdf');
```

When commenting from `$pdf->addPDF`, the success alert pops-up(and the window.location).

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe your success callback is not being invoked due to a server error? Add a complete callback and see if that returns with a status message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fileArray= $filer;

$datadir = "../dir/";
$outputName = $datadir."/filename.pdf";


$cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$outputName ";
//Add each pdf file to the end of the command
foreach($filer as $file) {
    $cmd .= $file." ";

}
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
```